# jqGrid doesn't read JSON without square brakcets

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, jqgrid

I used this code for APIs that were surrounded with square brackets and it worked. However, it doesn't work for an API that looks like this:

```
{"name":"Summer Tire","description":"Premium Summer Tires.","notes":"Good price","supplier":"Tire Systems","price":79,"currency":"EUR","ID":2}
```

Here is my code:

```
function loadMaterialDetails(id) {
    $("#materialDetails").jqGrid("GridUnload"); 

    $("#materialDetails").jqGrid({
        url: url,
        mtype: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [
            { label: 'Material ID',     name: 'ID', key: true, width: 1 },
            { label: 'Material Name',   name: 'name', width: 2 },
            { label: 'Supplier',        name: 'supplier', width: 2 },
            { label: 'Description',     name: 'description', width: 3 },
            { label: 'Notes',           name: 'notes', width: 1 },
            { label: 'Price',           name: 'price', width: 1 },
            { label: 'Currency',        name: 'currency', width: 1 }
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        width: 780,
        height: 250,
        rowNum: 20,
        onSelectRow: function(id){ 
          alert(id);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
I gave up on it. If I know that only one row could ever be acquired I fetch it with getJSON and manipulate it manually. Thanks for you input guys!

Comment: The grid requires an array of rows to be returned. Apparently, your API is only returning a single row.

Comment: I see that, but can I somehow force it to display a single row?

Comment: how does your backend code look like?

Comment: I only have access to this API and have to display the data, I use grids for other APIs where there are multiple rows so I didn't want to use different technology just for this one

Comment: one posibility is to load that json and append it in a array, after that reference it to the jqgrid

Comment: What would be the easiest way to load it?

Comment: @KamilSucharski: I forget to add small modification to the code. See UPDATED part of my answer. The code changes was in the comments which are deleted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Oleg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36788757/1835379) works, it is incomplete.

Try this:

```
jsonReader: {
    root: function (obj) {
        return obj instanceof Array ? obj : [obj];
    }
}
```

This will ensure that the grid will continue to work when the returned data is an array of rows, while also allowing it to render the single row / object.

Comment: I suggested you before to use `$.isArray(obj) ? obj : [obj];` and you changed  it to `obj instanceof Array ? obj : [obj];`. I don't see any real advantage: it's do the same. Sorry, for misunderstanding who is the owner of the question. Next time please write something like "it's Kamil Sucharski's question" instead of repeating "this is NOT MY QUESTION", which have more meaning. :-)

Comment: I didn't want to literally copy your code, @Oleg. The 2nd time I said _"This is not my question"_ should've been enough of a hint that I didn't write the question.

Comment: "This is not my question" have the meaning "You answer, not what I asked" and not just "another person asked the question". Isn't so?

Comment: If I had written the question, and your answer didn't answer it, I'd have said: _"This does not answer my question"_. _"This is not my question"_ Literally means that the _question_ is _not mine_.

Comment: A simple misunderstanding. Maybe "I am not the OP" would do from next time. :)

Answer (score -2):

Everything is possible. You need to add `jsonReader` with `root` defined as function:

```
jsonReader: {
    root: function (obj) {
        return [obj];
    }
}
```

See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/kLsqk8gc/ which displays the results like

[image]

**UPDATED:** I forget to add small changes posted before in the discussion, which is deleted now. If the response in not always object, but could be correct (array too) then one can just use:

```
jsonReader: {
    root: function (obj) {
        return $.isArray(obj) ? obj : [obj];
    }
}
```

Comment: **Moderator note:** comments removed. Comments to questions/answers should remain constructive, civil  and used for clarification purposes only. Thank you.

Comment: @JonClements: Thank you!